# Display the register form instead of a login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, shopify, liquid

I'm using a Shopify theme called Basal. At the top of my site there is a login/register link. When you press the "login/register" link the login widget pops out from the side (ex: https://new-basel2.myshopify.com/?key=f7fb74c55f142b94a98cab2918807f42f8f3e861bf52cd098b74bd9d13416020)

The form automatically shows the login side first, and then you can press the "create an account" link at the bottom of the form and it will show the register side while hiding the login side.

My question is how can I show the register side first when some presses the login/register button? Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried to mess around with the element "register_sidediv", and use the "showFormLogin" and "hideFormLogin" functions but nothing has worked.

Here are the two files associated with the login/register side popup

login_side.liquid -

```html
{%- assign gl_shopify_error = false -%}
<div class="login-form-side">
   <div class="widget-heading">
      <h3 class="widget-title">{{ 'general.login_popup.title' | t }}</h3>
      <a href="#" class="widget-close">{{ 'general.login_popup.close' | t }}</a>
   </div>
   <div class="login-form">
      <div class="shopify-message resetSuccessside" style="display:none;">{{ 'customer.recover_password.success' | t }}</div>
      <p class="text_content_success resetSuccessside" style="display:none;">{{ 'customer.recover_password.content_success' | t }}</p>
      <ul id="gl_shopify_errorside" class="shopify-error" style="display:none;">
         <li class="html_li" id="jas_html_frmside"></li>
      </ul>
      {%- form 'customer_login', id: "customer_login_side",class:'login shopify-form shopify-form-login' -%}
         {%- if form.errors -%}
            {%- assign gl_shopify_error = true -%}
            {%- for field in form.errors -%}
               {%- if field == 'form' -%}
                  {%- assign error_html = form.errors.messages[field] -%}
               {%- else -%}
                  {%- assign error_html = form.errors.translated_fields[field] | append:form.errors.messages[field] -%}
               {%- endif -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
         {%- endif -%}
         <p class="shopify-FormRow shopify-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="usernameside">{{ 'customer.login.email' | t }} <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="shopify-Input shopify-Input--text input-text{%- if form.errors contains 'email' %} input--error{%- endif -%}" name="customer[email]" id="usernameside" value="">
         </p>
         {%- if form.password_needed -%}
            <p class="shopify-FormRow shopify-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
               <label for="passwordside">{{ 'customer.login.password' | t }} <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input class="shopify-Input shopify-Input--text input-text{%- if form.errors contains 'password' %} input--error{%- endif -%}" type="password" name="customer[password]" id="passwordside">
            </p>
            <p class="shopify-LostPassword lost_password">
               <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showRecoverPasswordFormSide();return false;">{{ 'customer.login.forgot_password' | t }}</a>
            </p>
         {%- endif -%}
         <p class="form-row">
            <input type="submit" class="shopify-Button button" name="login" value="{{ 'customer.login.sign_in' | t }}">
         </p>
      {%- endform -%}

         <div id="register_sidediv" style="display: none">
            {%- form 'create_customer',id:'register_side',class:'login shopify-form shopify-form-login' -%}
               {%- if form.errors -%}
                  {%- assign gl_shopify_error = true -%}
                  {%- for field in form.errors -%}
                     {%- if field == 'form' -%}
                        {%- assign error_html = form.errors.messages[field] -%}
                     {%- else -%}
                        {%- assign error_html = form.errors.translated_fields[field] | append:form.errors.messages[field] -%}
                     {%- endif -%}
                  {%- endfor -%}
               {%- endif -%}
               <p class="shopify-FormRow shopify-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                  <label for="FirstNamereg">{{ 'customer.register.first_name' | t }}</label>
                  <input type="text" name="customer[first_name]" id="FirstNamereg"{%- if form.first_name %} value="{{ form.first_name }}"{%- endif %} autofocus>
               </p>
               <p class="shopify-FormRow shopify-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                  <label for="LastNamereg">{{ 'customer.register.last_name' | t }}</label>
                  <input type="text" name="customer[last_name]" id="LastNamereg"{%- if form.last_name %} value="{{ form.last_name }}"{%- endif -%}>
               </p>
               <p class="shopify-FormRow shopify-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                  <label for="reg_emailreg">{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }} <span class="required">*</span></label>
                  <input type="email" class="shopify-Input shopify-Input--text input-text{%- if form.errors contains 'email' %} input--error{%- endif -%}" name="customer[email]" id="reg_emailreg"{%- if form.email %} value="{{ form.email }}"{%- endif -%}>
               </p>
               <p class="shopify-FormRow shopify-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                  <label for="reg_passwordreg">{{ 'customer.register.password' | t }} <span class="required">*</span></label>
                  <input type="password" class="shopify-Input shopify-Input--text input-text{%- if form.errors contains 'password' %} input--error{%- endif -%}" name="customer[password]" id="reg_passwordreg" required="required">
                  <div class="shopify-password-strength" aria-live="polite"></div>
               </p>
               <p class="shopify-FormRow form-row">          
                  <input type="submit" class="shopify-Button button" name="register" value="{{ 'customer.register.submit' | t }}">
               </p>
            {%- endform -%}
        </div>
       <div id="recover_passwordside" style="display: none">
         {%- form 'recover_customer_password',id:'reset_password_side', class:'shopify-ResetPassword lost_reset_password' -%}
            <p class="gl_mb_0 gl_first">{{ 'customer.recover_password.subtext' | t }}</p>
            {%- if form.posted_successfully? -%}
               {%- assign reset_success = true -%}
            {%- endif -%}
            {%- if form.errors -%}
               {%- assign gl_shopify_error = true -%}
               {%- for field in form.errors -%}
                  {%- if field == 'form' -%}
                     {%- assign error_html = form.errors.messages[field] -%}
                  {%- else -%}
                     {%- assign error_html = form.errors.translated_fields[field] | append:form.errors.messages[field] -%}
                  {%- endif -%}
               {%- endfor -%}
            {%- endif -%}
            <p class="shopify-form-row shopify-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
               <label for="RecoverEmailside">{{ 'customer.recover_password.email' | t }}</label>
               <input type="email" value="" name="email" id="RecoverEmailside" class="shopify-Input shopify-Input--text input-text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p class="shopify-form-row form-row">
               <input type="submit" class="shopify-Button button" value="{{ 'customer.recover_password.submit' | t }}">
               <button type="button" onclick="hideRecoverPasswordFormSide();return false;" class="shopify-Button button">{{ 'customer.recover_password.cancel' | t }}</button>
            </p>
         {%- endform -%}
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="register-question">
      <span class="create-account-text">{{ 'general.login_popup.account_text' | t }}</span>
      <p>{{ settings.registration_text }}</p>
      <a class="btn btn-style-link" href="/account/register" id="hideFormLogin" onclick="hideFormLogin();return false;">{{ 'general.login_popup.register' | t }}</a>
      <a class="btn btn-style-link" href="/account/login" id="showFormLogin" onclick="showFormLogin();return false;" style="display:none">{{ 'general.login_popup.login' | t }}</a>
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*
    Show/hide the recover password form when requested.
  */
  function showRecoverPasswordFormSide() {
    document.getElementById('recover_passwordside').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('customer_login_side').style.display='none';
  }

  function hideRecoverPasswordFormSide() {
    document.getElementById('recover_passwordside').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('customer_login_side').style.display = 'block';
  }
  function hideFormLogin() {
    document.getElementById('register_sidediv').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('customer_login_side').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('showFormLogin').style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.getElementById('hideFormLogin').style.display='none';
  }

  function showFormLogin() {
    document.getElementById('register_sidediv').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('customer_login_side').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('hideFormLogin').style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.getElementById('showFormLogin').style.display='none';
  }
  // Allow deep linking to the recover password form
  //if (window.location.hash == '#recover') { showRecoverPasswordForm() }

  // reset_success is only true when the reset form is
  {% if reset_success -%}
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('resetSuccessside');
    x[0].style.display = 'block';  x[1].style.display = 'block';
  {% endif -%}
   {% if gl_shopify_error -%}
      {%- if error_html != blank -%}
      var html = {{error_html | json }};
      var element = document.getElementById("jas_html_frmside");
         element.innerHTML = '';
         element.innerHTML = '{{ 'customer.login.error' | t }} '+html;
      
      {%- endif -%}
      document.getElementById('gl_shopify_errorside').style.display = 'block';
  {% endif -%}
</script>
```

functions.js -

```html
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             * Login sidebar
             *-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             */
             
            loginSidebar: function() {
                if ($( '.login-form-side' ).length === 0) return;
                var body = $( 'body' );
                $( '.login-side-opener' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if( isOpened() ) {
                        closeWidget();
                    } else {
                        setTimeout( function() {
                            openWidget();
                        }, 10);
                    }
                });
                
                body.on( 'click touchstart', '.basel-close-side', function() {
                    if( isOpened() ) closeWidget();
                });

                body.on( 'click', '.widget-close', function( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if( isOpened() ) closeWidget();
                });
                
                var closeWidget = function() {
                    body.removeClass( 'basel-login-side-opened' );
                };

                var openWidget = function() {
                    body.addClass( 'basel-login-side-opened' );
                };
                
                var isOpened = function() {
                    return body.hasClass( 'basel-login-side-opened' );
                };

            },
          
            
            /**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to adapt the code as the following:

Add the "hideFormLogin" after the e.preventDefault();

This should call the switching function when the Sidebar open link is clicked.
This should work for both desktop and mobile.

```html
             
            loginSidebar: function() {
                if ($( '.login-form-side' ).length === 0) return;
                var body = $( 'body' );
                $( '.login-side-opener' ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    hideFormLogin();
                    
                    if( isOpened() ) {
                        closeWidget();
                    } else {
                        setTimeout( function() {
                            openWidget();
                        }, 10);
                    }
                });
                
                body.on( 'click touchstart', '.basel-close-side', function() {
                    if( isOpened() ) closeWidget();
                });

                body.on( 'click', '.widget-close', function( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if( isOpened() ) closeWidget();
                });
                
                var closeWidget = function() {
                    body.removeClass( 'basel-login-side-opened' );
                };

                var openWidget = function() {
                    body.addClass( 'basel-login-side-opened' );
                };
                
                var isOpened = function() {
                    return body.hasClass( 'basel-login-side-opened' );
                };

            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this javascript code to the footer of your template:

```
<script>hideFormLogin();</script>
```

I looked into your template and this is the function which hides the Login form and show the register form in the sidebar.
It also works if the sidebar is hidden, then the register form is shown when the sidebar opens.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would there be a way to add this into the functions.js for the login sidebar instead of the template?

Comment: I'm gonna make a second answer for this.